# Restrict access to reset_password form of Django in PasswordResetView in case the user is already logged in

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, backend

Currently, I have a user model that can access account related information based on its session. I am using the django auth `PasswordResetView`. The password reset form is used to reset password if the user has forgotten his/her password. But this Django view is also accessed by the user when he is already logged in.

How can I restrict the user to access this page? I cannot find solution for this problem, since it's a total abstraction and nothing is present in my `views.py` file.

This is how my **urls.py** file looks like :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mainapp.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name="login"),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name="logout"),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name="password_reset"),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name="password_reset_done"),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('password_reset_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name="password_reset_complete"),
    path('change_password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='users/change_password.html', success_url="/"), name="password_change"),
    # path('password_change_done/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_change_done.html'), name="password_change_done"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

A logged in user should not be able to access password_reset_form since it is only meant when the password is forgotten and when the user is already logged in, it does not make sense for the user to access `password_reset.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to modify the default views, one option would be to subclass them and use them in your urls.

In your views (using [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) class):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView

class MyPasswordResetView(UserPassesTestMixin, PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'users/password_reset.html'

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_anonymous
```

In your urls:

```
from .views import MyPasswordResetView

...
    path(
        'password_reset/', 
        MyPasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name="password_reset"),
...
```

---

You should learn to read the linked docs to find your answers. It says [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin.test_func):

> [...] you can set any of the parameters of `AccessMixin` to customize the handling of unauthorized users [...]

And under [`AccessMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin) you can find the attributes and methods to redirect unauthorized users.

Comment: I didn't get the form_valid method, can you explain what it is doing and what should I include inside `if not self.request.user.is_anonymous:
           # ... do something here ...
`

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I edited my answer and included `UserPassesTestMixin`

Comment: Currently if the user is trying to access the reset_page, its showing 403 error page can you tell me how can I redirect the user to homepage, and not the 403 error page. After that I ll accept this as answer to this question.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar you should learn to read the docs I linked in my answer, because in there you can find your answers; I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple ways to do this; However, I think that the quickest solution would be to write a decorator:

```
def login_forbidden(function=None):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_anonymous,
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

and use it to decorate the password reset views where you want to restrict access only to unauthenticated users:

```
path('password_reset/', login_forbidden(auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html')), name="password_reset")
```

Alternatively, you can override the actual views.

Comment: its little complicated, can you please explain what the code is doing

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar it seems to be based on the [login-required-decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator), just that it checks for the oposite case

Comment: ^ what Ralf said.

Comment: You can also pass a redirect page to `user_passes_tests`, maybe `index` where to redirect users which are logged in.

Comment: Can you point me to the django documentation which states how to handle these cases

Comment: Besides Ralf's link, you can have a look over this: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py

Comment: In the code why are you checking `u.is_anonymous` instead of if user is logged in or not. Can we do it the other way?

Comment: What will our variables `actual_decorator`  and `function` of if function contains after processing?

Comment: This is pretty smart !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` or `{% if user.is_anonymous %}` and put that directly in your template no need to modify the view:

```
{% if user.is_anonymous %}
# user is not logged in
...
{% else %}
# user is logged in
...
{% endif %}
```